# How does image loading actually work?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm working with NetBeans and loading images into my program, so far I have been storing all my images in src/images/ which was fine. But I wanted to capitalise all my package names so I refactored them all so that they were capitalised. so "images" became "Images". I changed all the file path strings to reflect this but when I ran my program the next time none of the images would load. I found another folder called images in the build part of my project which had a few of the images I needed in it so I copied everything from my src image folder into the /build/classes/images folder and then miraculously it started working again. Up until this point I have been putting all the images in the src/images/ section.

**So what is actually happening? Do I need to start saving all new images I want for the program in /build/classes/images or in the old place? What is going that the image loading code has decided to look in a completely different place now? And why are there two versions of the image folder? Is this some strange thing that NetBeans generates?**

```
ImageIO.read(myClass.class.getResource("/images/myClassImg.png");
```

Comment: Make sure you clean and build the project to ensure that the changes are reflected in the compiled code and netbeans cache

Answer (score 0):

A resource file can be packed with all .class files in a jar. And then it is not a file on the file system. And as a consequence the path names are case sensitive and use '/' as path separator. In general resource URLs are case sensitive.

Above it should have been "/Images/myClassImg.png".

However using capitalized package names is contrary to very widespread conventions.

Answer (score 0):

The `GetClass()` function should work. You can also use `getAbsolutePath()`.

```
Image I = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/myClassImg.png"));
```